# Speed up loading WPF pages in Frame control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a few pages which are very big (11 000 XAML code lines) and it gets nearly 1.5-2 seconds to completely load and display the page. So, my question is: how to speed up loading of such pages? 
Maybe I can load all pages at once at startup and then just switch between or something like that?
Who can tell me?